# Начало анимации при достижении элемента в поле зрения при скролле

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

Использую GreenSock.
Как сделать в данном примере так, чтобы анимация выполнялась только тогда, когда я дойду до блока?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  .circle {
   background-color: #777;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
  .main {
   height: 1500px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main"></div>
 <div class="circle"></div>



 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   const elementUno = document.querySelector('.circle');
   TweenLite.to(elementUno, 2, {x: 200} );
  }, false);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант #1:** 
C использованием библиотеки [ScrollMagic.](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Как пример, думаю, буде легко применить и к вопросу выше:

```js
const animatedElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.animated'));
  
  animatedElements.forEach(elem => {
   
    
    let scrollMagicController = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    var title = elem.querySelectorAll('div');
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
   
    tl.staggerFrom(title, 0.3, {x: "-10%", opacity: 0}, .25)
    
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: elem,
      offset: 0
    })
    .setTween(tl)
 .reverse(false)
    .addTo(scrollMagicController)
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.wrapper .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .row > * {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, soluta vitae ab nemo mollitia obcaecati pariatur magni animi quis assumenda suscipit labore aliquam vel? Quia cupiditate adipisci dicta molestiae in ullam eaque. Doloribus odio recusandae ipsum culpa tempore quasi quibusdam eligendi quis quos facere repudiandae, placeat totam est laborum sint commodi vitae magni enim magnam in maxime inventore suscipit? Optio voluptatum fugit ex mollitia perspiciatis explicabo? Error corrupti architecto molestias qui consequuntur dolorum a ipsam quis voluptas velit iste hic minima, voluptate natus unde rem dolore eos magnam dicta nobis obcaecati sed odit? Molestias perspiciatis vitae neque alias, esse qui cumque optio! Vitae eius, dolorum perferendis nihil vero provident dicta expedita mollitia culpa dolores, asperiores voluptates autem nostrum error illum rem voluptate rerum optio dolorem iure ullam. Dolor sit pariatur quasi nisi dignissimos beatae iste, doloribus dolores ullam sapiente non at voluptatem asperiores a culpa magni eaque facere esse ex quae nobis distinctio officia. Alias maxime voluptatum nemo velit, voluptates iste dolorum culpa quidem omnis sint explicabo veniam, dignissimos impedit. Sunt sed dolor animi nostrum illum, corrupti dolorum repellat. Minus aspernatur molestias earum maxime laborum! Reiciendis facere quam, totam cumque incidunt, voluptas quod voluptates excepturi in ut beatae cum. Minus!</div>
 <div class="row animated">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
 </div>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, soluta vitae ab nemo mollitia obcaecati pariatur magni animi quis assumenda suscipit labore aliquam vel? Quia cupiditate adipisci dicta molestiae in ullam eaque. Doloribus odio recusandae ipsum culpa tempore quasi quibusdam eligendi quis quos facere repudiandae, placeat totam est laborum sint commodi vitae magni enim magnam in maxime inventore suscipit? Optio voluptatum fugit ex mollitia perspiciatis explicabo? Error corrupti architecto molestias qui consequuntur dolorum a ipsam quis voluptas velit iste hic minima, voluptate natus unde rem dolore eos magnam dicta nobis obcaecati sed odit? Molestias perspiciatis vitae neque alias, esse qui cumque optio! Vitae eius, dolorum perferendis nihil vero provident dicta expedita mollitia culpa dolores, asperiores voluptates autem nostrum error illum rem voluptate rerum optio dolorem iure ullam. Dolor sit pariatur quasi nisi dignissimos beatae iste, doloribus dolores ullam sapiente non at voluptatem asperiores a culpa magni eaque facere esse ex quae nobis distinctio officia. Alias maxime voluptatum nemo velit, voluptates iste dolorum culpa quidem omnis sint explicabo veniam, dignissimos impedit. Sunt sed dolor animi nostrum illum, corrupti dolorum repellat. Minus aspernatur molestias earum maxime laborum! Reiciendis facere quam, totam cumque incidunt, voluptas quod voluptates excepturi in ut beatae cum. Minus!</div>
 <div class="row animated" data-animation="multiple">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
 </div>
 
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, soluta vitae ab nemo mollitia obcaecati pariatur magni animi quis assumenda suscipit labore aliquam vel? Quia cupiditate adipisci dicta molestiae in ullam eaque. Doloribus odio recusandae ipsum culpa tempore quasi quibusdam eligendi quis quos facere repudiandae, placeat totam est laborum sint commodi vitae magni enim magnam in maxime inventore suscipit? Optio voluptatum fugit ex mollitia perspiciatis explicabo? Error corrupti architecto molestias qui consequuntur dolorum a ipsam quis voluptas velit iste hic minima, voluptate natus unde rem dolore eos magnam dicta nobis obcaecati sed odit? Molestias perspiciatis vitae neque alias, esse qui cumque optio! Vitae eius, dolorum perferendis nihil vero provident dicta expedita mollitia culpa dolores, asperiores voluptates autem nostrum error illum rem voluptate rerum optio dolorem iure ullam. Dolor sit pariatur quasi nisi dignissimos beatae iste, doloribus dolores ullam sapiente non at voluptatem asperiores a culpa magni eaque facere esse ex quae nobis distinctio officia. Alias maxime voluptatum nemo velit, voluptates iste dolorum culpa quidem omnis sint explicabo veniam, dignissimos impedit. Sunt sed dolor animi nostrum illum, corrupti dolorum repellat. Minus aspernatur molestias earum maxime laborum! Reiciendis facere quam, totam cumque incidunt, voluptas quod voluptates excepturi in ut beatae cum. Minus!</div>
</div>
```

Обязательно обратить внимание, что нужно так же подключить этот плагин:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js

**Вариант #2:**

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
const tl = new TimelineMax({
 paused: true
})
tl.to(circle, 1, {opacity: 1, x: '300%'})

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
 const circle_position = circle.offsetTop - window.innerHeight + circle.offsetHeight / 2;
 let scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 if(circle_position <= scrolled) {
  tl.play();
 }
})
```

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #777;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.main {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Оно теперь 2 дня грузиться )

Comment: Он не грузится два дня, потому как с этой библиотекой проблем замечено не было, и на нее официально ссылаются разработчики GSAP. Добавил второй вариант реализации.